# Create SQL Server tables during deployment

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

Is it possible to create SQL Server tables during deployment?

Here is my code:

```
resource sqlDataBase 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases@2021-02-01-preview' = {
  name: sqlServerName
  parent: sqlServer
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'GP_S_Gen5'
    tier: 'GeneralPurpose'
    family: 'Gen5'
    capacity: 4
  }
}

resource SourceTableA 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/tables@2022-11-01-preview' = {
  parent: sqlDataBase
  name: 'SourceTableA'
  properties: {
    columns: [
      {
        name: 'Id'
        type: 'INT'
      }
      {
        name: 'Name'
        type: 'NVARCHAR(255)'
      }
      {
        name: 'Age'
        type: 'NVARCHAR(255)'
      }
    ]
    primaryKey: {
      columns: ['Id']
    }
  }
}

resource SourceTableB 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/tables@2022-11-01-preview' = {
  parent: sqlDataBase
  name: 'SourceTableB'
  properties: {
    columns: [
      {
        name: 'Id'
        type: 'INT'
      }
      {
        name: 'Address'
        type: 'NVARCHAR(255)'
      }
      {
        name: 'Location'
        type: 'NVARCHAR(255)'
      }      
    ]
    primaryKey: {
      columns: ['Id']
    }
  }
}
```

I get this error:

> {"code":"DeploymentFailed","target":"/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/sqlServerTemplate","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"The specified resource 'subscriptions/xxx/resourcegroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/xxx/databases/xxx/tables/SourceTableB' was not found."},{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"The specified resource 'subscriptions/xxx/resourcegroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/xxx/databases/xxx/tables/SourceTableA' was not found."}]}

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no resource type called `Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/tables`
According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/servers/databases/schemas/tables?pivots=deployment-language-bicep) there is a `Microsoft.Sql servers/databases/schemas/tables` resource type but it is **read-only**:

> This resource type is read-only, which means it can't be deployed but an existing instance can be referenced. Typically, read-only resource types are automatically created by the service.
>
> Use the `existing` keyword.

Few options for you:

- Generate a bacpbac and import it: [Tutorial: Import SQL BACPAC files with ARM templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-tutorial-deploy-sql-extensions-bacpac)
- Use a deployment script extension to create the tables: [Use deployment scripts in Bicep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/deployment-script-bicep)

To be honest, This could become complicated and you could always run the tables creation after the bicep deployment.